# Can python breakpoint() be disabled in a script (with VSCode debugger)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to use the new (python 3.7+) `breakpoint()`. During initial devlopment, I want to be able to disable all breakpoints within the script. Is this possible?

I tried setting PYTHONBREAKPOINT environmental variable to 0 at the top of the script, but the debugger still stops at each one. Does the env var have to set before the script is initialised? or does it need to be set to something else?

I'm using VSCode debugger, working in a virtual env, on windows 10.

```
    import os

    os.environ['PYTHONBREAKPOINT'] = "0"

    a = 1

    print(os.environ['PYTHONBREAKPOINT'])  # prints 0
    breakpoint()  # debugger still stops here

    b = 2
```

Edit: If i use pdb in the command line, breakpoints are disabled. So it is VSCode debugger related
Edit2: Appears to be VSCode debugger specific. Accepted answer work for me, but means cannot use different dev and production environments to suppress breakpoints, have to change the code instead.

Comment: I've tried setting it as the interger (0), but that can't be done in a script. I've also just set the env var manually and reopened VSCode, and still the same issue.

Comment: This code works as you expect in IDLE with Python 3.7.3; maybe it's a limitation of VSCode, possibly it doesn't handle re-loading environment variables properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set `sys.breakpointhook`, a function that is called when `breakpoint()` is executed:

```
import sys

sys.breakpointhook = lambda *x: None  # function that does nothing

a = 1
breakpoint()
b = 2
```

Comment: But the breakpoint() documentation specifically says "PYTHONBREAKPOINT is re-interpreted every time sys.breakpointhook() is reached. This allows processes to change its value during the execution of a program and have breakpoint() respond to those changes."

Comment: Good point. "Specifically, with [0] sys.breakpointhook() returns None immediately." Maybe VSCode's debugger doesn't know about that?

Comment: Yeah, It appears to be VSCode. Setting the envvar in the script or in the sysyem before opening both work for pdb in the command line, and both don't work for VSCode. This answer does the job for now, so i'll accept (although it makes mypy show an anoying error!)

Comment: For those who are interested, VS Code uses https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy, so this fix steals it from `debugpy`.

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my Pytest code for tests that are meant to hit breakpoints:

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def ignore_breakpoint():
    with patch.dict(os.environ, {'PYTHONBREAKPOINT': '0'}):  # when running from the command line
        with patch('sys.breakpointhook', lambda *args: None):  # when running via VS Code
            yield
```